# It keeps looping at the second elif

Tags: python, lexer

It cant get past the second elif. The code is part of a interpreter in Python 3.7 [This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EISza.png)

```
def make_tokens(self):
    tokens = []
    while self.current_char is not None:
        if self.current_char.isspace():
            print("debug if")
            self.advance()
            continue
        elif self.current_char == "''":
            print("debug elif 1")
            tokens.append(Token(STRING, self.string()))
        elif self.current_char in LETTERS:
            print("debug elif 2")
            tokens.append(Token(IDENTIFIER, self.identifier))
    return(tokens)
    print("debug make tokens end")
```

Comment: Don't you need to `self.advance()` in _each_ branch of the loop?

Comment: You might want to consider looking at the `pyparsing` module which is a library for building parsers with little code if this isn't just a learning exercise or a trivial task.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because `self.current_char` is in `LETTER` at the first iteration. Then, you do not change it inside the second `if` so it keeps being in LETTERS.

You should do:

```
def make_tokens(self):
    tokens = []
    while self.current_char is not None:
        if self.current_char.isspace():
            print("debug if")

            # self.advance() remove this

            # continue remove this
        elif self.current_char == "''":
            print("debug elif 1")
            tokens.append(Token(STRING, self.string()))
        elif self.current_char in LETTERS:
            print("debug elif 2")
            tokens.append(Token(IDENTIFIER, self.identifier))

        self.advance() # add this

    return(tokens)
    print("debug make tokens end")
```

Comment: Pretty sure this will hang once `self.current_char.isspace()` becomes true.